# ASP. NET controller receives null array

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am writing Angular.js/ASP.NET application.
I have defined this model:

```
public class Dealer : EntityBase
{
    ...
    public virtual List<DealerDefinedService> DealerDefinedServices { get; set; }
    public virtual List<DealerDefinedServicesDiscount> DealerDefinedServicesDiscounts { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

And I have a controller that can receive that model:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Dealer model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        dealerService.EditDealer(model);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View("Create", model);
}
```

In my Angular.js controller I am trying to send this object:

```
{
  "DealerDefinedServices": [
    {
      ...
    }
  ],
  "DealerDefinedServicesDiscounts": [
    {
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

If both "DealerDefinedServices" and "DealerDefinedServicesDiscounts" parameters are set, ASP.NET controller receives only one of them, but other becomes null. I was trying to fix this problem for hours and finally fixed it by renaming one of mentioned parameters because I thought that maybe the problem is that parameters have similar names. So, what's the problem, why controller can't see one of parameters if they have simillar names?

Comment: So the problem is fixed? If they had the same names within your `json`, how would you suppose it would bind to your class if one was null and the other wasn't?

Comment: Names are not the same, they are simillar: "DealerDefinedServices" and "DealerDefinedServicesDiscounts". One of them becomes null if both provided. Problem is fixed by renaming one of parameters to something new, not simillar "DealerDefinedServices" to "Abc". But my question is, why controller can't allow me to use my mentioned names?

Comment: show your javascript and how you set your values to be sent to the controller.

Comment: @Ric post-method: `$http.post('/Dealers/Edit', $scope.model).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    $window.location.href = '/Dealers/Index';
                }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

                });`

Comment: It might be the FormValueProvider  in the model binder getting confused.
It has a ContainsPrefix(String) method which might be the culprit.
Can you try renaming the second parameter to Dealer1DefinedServices Discounts and try again and  see if it works ? 
Then try it again by naming it  DealerDefinedServices1Discounts and check again . If its the ContainsPrefix the former should work for u and the later should reproduce the null issue.

Comment: @Pratik You are right, but for what purpose FormValueProvider uses ContainsPrefix method?

Comment: The default model binder  uses a FormValueProvider to extract a fields value out of the request and put it into the Dealer model. ContainsPrefix is one of the methods it uses to find the field in the request in this case your $scope.model object. My guess is the ContainsPrefix is returning incorrect info to the model binder since the prefix "DealerDefinedServices" is common for both the properties in your model. I do not have enough knowledge about model binders to comment on what is the sequence of execution of code and why model binder makes one property null

Comment: But the fact that if you make sure that the prefix strings different on the 2 properties makes the binding work would point to ContainsPrefix being the  culprit. Check this articke if you want a general idea of model binders http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001708/ch13.html#_how_model_binding_works it is geared more towards a custom model binder implementation than  explaining the default one but it should give you a idea of what FormValueProvider  are.

Comment: Another thing to try might be to use a WebAPI instead of a action method in MVC , The model binders for Action methods expect to receive a form object ( hence the name FormValeProvider) . Since what you are passing is essentially a json a WebAPI model binder might be more efficient in binding it

Comment: Let me know if this is helpful and i will put it together in a answer.

Comment: @Pratik thank you very much! Put it please in an answer, so people would be more careful with this. Also, I found that it is a bug in MVC4: http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/616

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be the `FormValueProvider` in the default model binder getting confused. 
It has a
 `ContainsPrefix(String)` 
method which might be the culprit. 
Try renaming the second parameter to

> Dealer1DefinedServicesDiscounts

and then try it again by naming it

> DealerDefinedServices1Discounts

The former should work properly while in the later  should reproduce the null issue.

**Reason for this behaviour**

The default model binder uses a **FormValueProvider** to extract a fields value out of the request and put it into your Dealer model. 
**FormValueProvider** uses the **ContainsPrefix** methods to find the field in the request in this case your $scope.model object. 
My guess is the ContainsPrefix is returning incorrect info to the model binder since the prefix ***DealerDefinedServices*** is common for both the properties in your model.

I do not have enough knowledge about model binders to comment on what is the sequence of execution of code and why model binder makes one property null.

As you have already tried already changing the property names so that they dont have same prefixes will work around this problem.

Another thing to try might be to use a WebAPI instead of a action method in MVC. The model binders for Action methods expect to receive a form object ( hence the name FormValueProvider) . Since what you are passing is essentially a json/javascript object a WebAPI model binder might be more efficient in binding it. Note : I havent tried it , it WebAPI may have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug in MVC4. Be careful. http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/616